# Will this permission cause an error? (The answer doesn't work?)

Tags: java, android, performance, android-activity, permissions

After doing tons of research on the topic, I learned that my app may not show up for tablets in the Play Store if I have some permissions that the tablet cannot handle. **Here are my current permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" android:permission ="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**Will any of these permissions cause the app to not show up in the play store?**

Some tablets may not be able to handle the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />` because don't get calls...So, I need to do something in my java code saying:

```
if(Device has the ability to get calls){ //Execute code}
```

So, since the telephone thing is optional, I changed it's permission to:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"  android:required="false"/>
```

How do I get that? If you need it, this is where I am actually checking if the user is getting a call, I use it to mute my application:

```
   private PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                onPhoneCallInterrupt(); //Method I created that just mutes the audio
            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {

            } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                onPhoneCallInterrupt(); //Method I created that just mutes the audio
            }
        }

    };
```

So, what do I do to handle the exception that may occur if a tablet is using the app, like this?

```
if(Device has the ability to get calls){ //Execute code}
```

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: will checking whether the device has sim card or not ? will help you in any manner ?

Comment: @ShvetChakra It may, and that's a really good idea. How would I check for that? For now though, I don't even know if it will cause an error!

Answer (score 0):

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  //gets the current TelephonyManager
if (tm.getSimState() != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT){
  //the device has a sim card
} else {
  //no sim card available
}
```

[Check more here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#SIM_STATE_ABSENT)

Comment: So after doing this, what would the permission in the manifest look like?

Comment: there will not be any change in the permission

Comment: If you need to check for phone state, then you will ask for user's permission to read the phone state from the IF block.

Comment: @IbtehazShawon Exactly...What do you suggest I do then? Will the app not get shown in the play store otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your phone state permission on an if-else block. When user will try to access that feature or you might need to check phone state, throw a dialog box on the screen. [This link](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) shows how to ask for user's permission.

From API 23, User's will need to explicitly permit each and every permission so, it is a good thing if you do that for all. 
Beside, upon users permission, the manifest file will be overwritten so, you won't have to worry about that either.

Does it solve ur issue?